# Cleanest way to reload Js files after UpdatePanel PostBack?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have many javascript files and after an asynchronous call via my update panel. my server controls loose their style and behaviour. I need to refresh my js files. So, what's the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Let me know if i understood your problem: You have some server controls that you modify on client-side. These controls are inside update panels. You lose the client-side changes after callbacks. You want to re-apply the client side-changes after each callback. Is this correct?

Comment: i have a server control (dropdown list) and it's using js files to acheive some functionality like filtring and autocomplete. It's placed in an update panel. After raising the SelectIndexChanged event of this dropdownlist. the second time it loose its style and functionnality. I need to refresh/reload my js files after the asynchronous postback

Comment: This behavior is expected. You can try handling the Ajax PageRequestManager beginRequest and endRequest events and save you control's state before a callback and restore it after. Also check for conflicts between the MS Ajax library and the libraries you are using for filtering and autocomplete.